# How to create a post from iPhone to Rails

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails-3, post

Newbie to Rails and iOS here. I have a Rails blog application with Post model that has just a title and and image. I can create a new Post from a browser using the following html.erb code:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <p>  
    <%= f.file_field :image %>  
  </p> 
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
```

But how would I do this from an iPhone app? Is there an equivalent form function in iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can recommend you using [ASIHttpRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/), especially the class ASIFormDataRequest. With this you can send form data easily as a POST request.

Comment: yes, and don't forget to disable "protection from forgery" in your rails app

Comment: Have you seen a good tutorial for ASIHttpRequest? Thanks for the suggesstion